# GCC issues a warning that my precompiled headers (.h.gch) are invalid

Tags: c, gcc, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to use precompiled headers for the first time.  I have the following rules in my Makefile:

```
$(UNITS_h_gch): $(builddir)/%.h.gch: $(INCLUDEDIR)/%.h   $(mk) \
                                   | $$(@D)/. $(builddir)/%.h.d
        $(info -        CC      $$builddir/$*.h.gch)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(INCLUDEDIR) -DPCH -S -o $@ $<

$(UNITS_c_s):   $(builddir)/%.c.s:   $(SRCDIR)/%.c   $(builddir)/alx/%.h.gch   $(mk) \
                                   | $$(@D)/. $(builddir)/%.c.d
        $(info -        CC      $$builddir/$*.c.s)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I $(builddir) -I $(INCLUDEDIR) -S -o $@ $<
```

The rule for the `.s` files is the same as before, except that it now depends also on the PCH, obviously; and also that it includes `$(builddir)` in the headers with `-I` to be able to use the precompiled headers that I generate there.

The nonstandard notation (`.c.s`) is to simplify the Makefile, as I also have `.cxx.s` files which follow a slightly different rule, using g++ of course.

As GCC documentation says (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html), I used the same command line to produce the PCHs.  It failed due to `#pragma once`, so I added a conditional in the headers to remove it when building the PCH;  that's why I define `PCH` with `-DPCH`.

I've seen that people compiles PCHs with `-c`, but I also produce temporary assembly files, so I used `-S`.  May that be the cause f the failure?

Logs:

```
$ make
-   CC  $builddir/alx/base/assert/array.h.gch
-   CC  $builddir/base/assert/array.c.s
/home/alx/src/alx/libalx/src/base/assert/array.c:10:35: error: /home/alx/src/alx/libalx/tmp/alx/base/assert/array.h.gch: not a PCH file [-Werror]
   10 | #include <alx/base/assert/array.h>
      |                                   ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [/home/alx/src/alx/libalx/lib/recipes.inc.mk:49: /home/alx/src/alx/libalx/tmp/base/assert/array.c.s] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:63: base] Error 2
```

I'm seeing an error because of `-Werror`, and that appeared after adding `-Winvalid-pch`.  Before that the compilation was successful, but because it was taking the original header file, and not the precompiled one.  I suspected of this, because the compilation was twice as slow.

BTW, I use bracket includes (`<...>`) because this is a library that I install in the system and then use from other programs.

Comment: Macro definitions must be IDENTICAL. So defining your PCH define is not going to work. And it looks like your rule to produce the gch file is producing assembler output. That won't work, ever. And I found it was important to specifically declare the type of header, in my case I had to use `-x c++-header $<` but you probably want `c-header`

Comment: Yes, I want a C header (I have separate .hxx headers, which I precompile identically but with g++). Okay, so the definition of `PCH` is probably the problem; I'll try to workaround `#pragma once` in a different way, or even patch GCC. About assembler output... I tried `gcc -S` and `gcc -c` and both appear to produce the same kind of output. If I open the files,both seem to be unreadable, and very similar. I think GCC is ignoring that option.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to use `c-header` just in case.

Comment: May I use sed to alter the file and try to fool gcc that way?  That way I could remove the pragma without changing the command line.

Comment: Even without the pragma at all, gcc still complains that it's not a valid file.  Is it just impossible to have intermediate assembler files if I have precompiled headers?  Am I forced to compile .c files into .o?

Comment: I skipped the .s file by directly producing .o files, and the compilation seems to work. I'm very surprised that I didn't receive any error after removing all of the `#pragma once` in the tree.  I'm not entirely happy about this, as I like to be able to see the output of the compiler, just in case I need to check something there.  Maybe I'll produce them but not actually use them...

Comment: The precompiled header files produced by GCC don't contain any assembler output that you'd be able to check anyway. It is designed to be sucked into the compiler and used immediately from its binary format. It is something like a memory dump from the compiler after include processing.